# Does arcpy have a method for accessing related records within a cursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, relationship-class

I have a line feature class that represent sampling segments.  I have a data table of field notes in the same Geodatabase that is connected to the feature class with a Relationship Class.

Is there a built in method for arcpy to access related records?  The work around would be to add another cursor for the second table, but you'd think that if you take the time to relate your data there would be a quick and easy method for accessing related records programatically.

Software: ArcGIS 10.1

Answer (score 3):

If there is such an inbuilt method for ArcPy then I am unaware of it.

Curiously, the ArcInfo Workstation architecture (which preceded ArcGIS for Desktop) had a cursor implementation within its Arc Macro Language (AML) that supported working with related records.

Comment: There is in ArcObjects, but not arcpy (yet). Perhaps someone could link to or create an ArcGIS idea?

Comment: [ESRI Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087E000000053klIAA) Please visit and up-vote if you agree so we can get the attention of ESRI.